# Object id is missing in Django framework when posted from AngularJS MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, django, mongodb

I am posting the following object

```
{
    skillName : "Professional Skills"
    _id : {$oid: "5adf23946ab671bf6cb36aff"}
    }
```

to the DjangoService given below:

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def saveSubjectView(request):  #this service will add & update Subject

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            stream = StringIO(request.body)
            subject = JSONParser().parse(stream)
            print("The subejct is ")
            pp.pprint(subject)
            serializedsubject = json.loads(json_util.dumps(subject))
            print("serializedsubject")
            pp.pprint(serializedsubject)
```

The output that I am getting is

```
'skillType': {   u'_id': {   }, u'skillName': u'Professional Skills'}
```

The ObjectId posted from the front end (AngularJS) is not printed in the service. I know that I can fix it by removing the $oid while posting from the AngularJS application. But I would like to know why this is not happening. I have searched the documents and I couldn't get a proper reply. May be the keywords I used are wrong. Keywords used are : "JSON serialisation of ObjectId", "$oid json serialization using Django".

The complete object I am posting to the Django service is given below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly. `$oid` or anything prefixed with `$` is an internal format and reserved, so you cannot post field names. The convention is from [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) where such prefixes are used to identify the BSON Type for proper conversion, and used as a serializable transport since these "types" are not supported in basic JSON.

So the solution is to actually use the [`bson.json_util`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html) to "deserialize" the JSON string right from the start:

```
from bson import json_util

# serializedsubject = json.loads(json_util.dumps(subject))
serializedsubject = json_util.loads(request.body)     # correct usage
```

Or more succinctly self contained:

```
input = '{ "skillName" : "Professional Skills" ,"_id" : { "$oid": "5adf23946ab671bf6cb36aff"} }'
json_util.loads(input)
```

Returns

```
{u'skillName': u'Professional Skills', u'_id': ObjectId('5adf23946ab671bf6cb36aff')}
```

This correctly casts objects from any keys notated with the Extended JSON Syntax to their correct BSON Type, as also supported in the driver functions. And naturally the driver will then convert back to BSON when sending to MongoDB.

If for some reason your `request.body` contains anything other than a "string" which is valid for input to the function, then it is up to your code to convert it to that point. But there should be no need to "parse to JSON" and then "stringify" again just to input to the function.

---

> **NOTE**: If you have not already done so within your JavaScript client side of the application, there is also the [`bson`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson) package available. This would allow where such Extended JSON is "received" from the server the translation into the BSON Types as JavaScript Objects, and of course then the serialization of such objects back into the Extended JSON Format.
>
> This would in fact be recommended where "type" information needs to be maintained with the data transmitted and kept between client and server.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. The code that you have given works when hard coded in the Python code. But when posted from the AngularJS, it still removed ObjectId field. Am I missing something?

Comment: @HarisNp What do you mean by *"..when posted from the AngularjS.."*? The content is is `request.body` is it not? In the code you wrote you are running through `JSONParser()` etc. I'm saying **don't do that** and simply deserialize the string content using the correct `json_util.joads`, which understands the extended JSON syntax and converts the types.

Comment: "When posted from the AngularJS .. means that I am calling the service from client side AngularJS application.  Please see the code below.        `serializedsubject = json_util.loads(request.body) 
            print('serializedsubject')
            pp.pprint(serializedsubject)
            print("-------------------------")

            input = '{ "skillName" : "Professional Skills" ,"_id" : { "$oid": "5adf23946ab671bf6cb36aff"} }'
            pp.pprint(json_util.loads(input))` The first one doesn't print the ObjectID. `u'skillType': {   u'_id': {   }, u'skillName': u'Personal Skills'},`

Comment: While doing further analysis I found that the client side is not posting _id to the python service. Looks like my question itself is wrong. Sorry about the wrong analysis. 
{"type":"parent","status":true,"activeFlag":1,"subjectName":".Haris","subjectCode":".Haris","subjectAlias":".Haris","skillType":{"_id":{},"skillName":"Personal Skills"},"companyId":"54cf439a4ed3269b80684820","crmId":"54cf439a4ed3269b8068481e","urmId":"54cf439a4ed3269b8068481e"}

Comment: @HarisNp Read the answer. I actually covered the serialization on the client side as well, as the client is likely using the BSON library so you need to "serialize" correctly from there as well. Also make sure you do something like `request.body.decode('utf-8')` in order to ensure you're getting a valid string to parse. Also, please don't post code in comments. If you need details clarified then add it to your question instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had missed the Note part. Sorry about that. It is very clear now. But I have solved the issue by using the following code on the client side.                                                  `if('skillType' in subject ) {
            if('_id' in subject.skillType){
                subject.skillType._id = subject.skillType._id.$oid;
            }

        }`. Which way is more efficient? Using a BSON package as mentioned in your note or just removing the **$oid** from JavaScript code as shown above?

Comment: @HarisNp use the BSON package. And on both ends. Far cleaner and portable.

Comment: Thank you very much and I will use BSON package on both ends.